# mongodb retrieve data and insert to different collection nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i'm trying to insert/copy? a data from a to b.

for example:

```
var styles = db.collection("style");

 this.getStylesByA = function(a, callback) {
    "use strict";
    styles.findOne({'a': a}, function(err, style) {
        "use strict";

        if (err) return callback(err, null);
        console.log(style);
        callback(err, style);
    });
}
```

this would give

```
"_id":_id,
"style":"12345",
"a":"a",
"price":1.00,
"desc":"asldkfjea",
"img":"http://",
"imgs":["http:/","http:/"],
"category":"top",
"colors":[black, white]
```

something like this.

what i want to do is, find a data from style collection, and insert a same data to product collection which is a different collection.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with a separate collection object.

```
var styles = db.collection("style");
var  products =   db.collection("products");

this.getStylesByA = function(a, callback) {

    "use strict";
    styles.findOne({'a': a}, function(err, style) {
        "use strict";
        if (err) return callback(err, null);
            console.log(style);
        //insert style object to products collection
        products.insert(style);

        callback(err, style);
    });

}
```